# Calculation of Hall Conductance from Feynman Diagram

Tags: feynman-diagrams, topological-insulators, quantum-anomalies, chern-simons-theory

I'm trying to understand the calculation of the Hall conductance for a Chern insulator from a field theory standpoint. Specifically, I want to understand how, when integrating out the fermions from some insulator lattice model, the effective action for the external gauge field includes a Chern-Simons with a coefficient equal to the Chern number.

To that end, I'd like to get some clarification regarding the Feynman diagram calculation in [1]. I'm a little unsure of their Eq. (2) (the coefficient of the Chern-Simons term) and I don't understand how they get to Eq. (4).

For Eq. (2), I understand the terms in the integral. The $q_i$ derivatives are present because we're interested in the contribution which is linear in $n$ out of the $n+1$ external momenta, right? And is the Levi-Civita symbol present to make sure we only get fully anti-symmetric contributions?

I see why Eq. (3) should hold in analogy with the continuum Dirac fermion. But I don't understand how they apply it to Eq. (2) to get Eq. (4). Where do the $q_i$ derivatives go? Are they Taylor expanding all the terms in integral about $q_i = 0$? How do they go from having $2n+1$ factors of propagators and vertex factors in Eq. (2) to having $2(2n+1)$ factors of propagators in Eq. (4)?

[1] Golterman, Jansen, Kaplan https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-lat/9209003

Comment: Tip: Consider to make the post self-contained.